# Consume versus Subsume?

Tags: synonyms, word-usage, comparisons

After reading the definitions of both, I can't see how these words differ, however, given their prefixes, I assume they must.

Could someone explain to me the difference between 'consume' and 'subsume', either in definition or their typical usage?

In particular, I'm referring to their usage in relation to absorption of another item.

Comment: They’re pretty different. Please [edit] to include the definitions you consulted.

Comment: Voting to close because this question can be easily answered by consulting a dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Merriam-Webster, [**subsume**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsume) has only one sense:

> transitive verb
>
> : to include or place within something larger or more comprehensive : encompass as a subordinate or component element • red, green, and yellow are *subsumed* under the term "color"
>
> games and team sports are *subsumed* under the classification of “recreation”

However, [**consume**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consume) has *nine* different senses:

> transitive verb
>
> **1** : to do away with completely : DESTROY • Fire *consumed* several buildings.
> **2 a** : to spend wastefully : SQUANDER • *consumed* his inheritance on luxuries
> **b** : use up •  Writing *consumed* much of his time.
> **3 a** : to eat or drink especially in great quantity • *consumed* several bags of pretzels
> **b** : to enjoy avidly : DEVOUR
>  • . . . mysteries, which she *consumes* for fun . . . —Eden Ross Lipson
> **4** : to engage fully : ENGROSS • *consumed* with curiosity
> **5** : to utilize as a customer • *consume* goods and services
>
> intransitive verb
>
> **1** : to waste or burn away : PERISH
> **2** : to utilize economic goods

Regardless of which of the senses of **consume** may be equated with *absoprtion*, none of them have the same specific meaning as **subsume**.

Even looking only at sense *3 a*, although you might **consume** three hot dogs, it would be awkward to say that you **subsume** them (within your body). *Eat* would be a synonym of this sense of **consume**, but it wouldn't be a synonym of **subsume**.

Also in the *absorption* sense, **subsume** generally means that something continues to exist as part of a larger whole, but **consume** generally means that something is destroyed in the process.

Comment: Thank you Jason, each part of your answer helped me better understand the differences.